# What does this parameter mean in this curve fi function?

Tags: solidity, tokens, vyper

I am trying to add 22 dai to a polygon curve pool. Here is the function I am using:
[image]

If I am trying to add 22 dai into the pool, what do I put for the parameters? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. `N_COINS` is the number of coins in the pool, for e.g. in 3pool (DAI/USDC/USDT) N_COINS = 3.
2. `_amounts` is an array representing the amounts with liquidity you are providing, for e.g. in 3pool [10, 15, 20] means you are providing 10 DAI, 15 USDC, 20 USDT.
3. `_min_mint_amount` is the minimal curve liquidity token for the pool you are willing to receive